# Android game software joystick

Tags: android, angle, joystick

Im looking for an easy way to move around a character and rotate it using a software joystick. Though, i have never done anything like this and have no idea about how to create one.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try to look at this post [joystick](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/TfOL1WHjXsI)